# How do I promisify the AWS JavaScript SDK?

Tags: node.js, promise, amazon-dynamodb, bluebird, aws-sdk

I want to use the aws-sdk in JavaScript using promises.

Instead of the default callback style:

```
dynamodb.getItem(params, function(err, data) {
  if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
  else     console.log(data);           // successful response
});
```

I instead want to use a [promise](http://wiki.commonjs.org/wiki/Promises) style:

```
dynamoDb.putItemAsync(params).then(function(data) {
  console.log(data);           // successful response
}).catch(function(error) {
  console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
});
```

Comment: So, have you tried to `bluebird.promisifyAll(dynamodb)`?

Comment: With bluebird `var dynamoDb = Promise.promisifyAll(new AWS.DynamoDB());`

Comment: Since aws-sdk@^2.3.0 has already support promise.
Note : bluebird.promisifyAll for aws-sdk@^2.3.0 will cause error `module initialization error: TypeError`

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I believe calls can now be appended with `.promise()` to promisify the given method.

You can see it start being introduced in 2.6.12 https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#2612

You can see an example of it's use in AWS' blog https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/node-js-8-10-runtime-now-available-in-aws-lambda/

```
let AWS = require('aws-sdk');
let lambda = new AWS.Lambda();

exports.handler = async (event) => {
    return await lambda.getAccountSettings().promise() ;
};
```

Comment: Note that this only works for some functions. From AWS Docs: "Note: This currently only works for operations that return an instance of AWS.Request."

Answer (score 32):

The 2.3.0 release of the AWS JavaScript SDK added support for promises: http://aws.amazon.com/releasenotes/8589740860839559

Comment: Which unfortunately isn't supported under Lambda. :-(

Comment: So, I've been trying to get this to work in Lambda and just found your comment.  Why doesn't this work in Lambda?  Where did you find that information?  Thanks!

Comment: It should work under lambda if you use node 4.3.2 and you can even change the Promise library. If you're using the node 0.10.x then you must change the Promise library becuase it's not available natively. For more info check this: https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js/blob/266875c2e6a6ef5f9ff875e2cdaf36e10018d2da/doc-src/guide/browser-making-requests.md#support-for-promises

Comment: Maybe this answer should mention how promise support is enabled in aws-sdk instead of just linking to an overview-ish page. Basically what's needed is `AWS.config.setPromisesDependency(Q.Promise);` to use Q, and corresponding for other promise implementations. More info at https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/developer/support-for-promises-in-the-sdk/, but please copy the content instead of just linking.

Answer (score 25):

You can use a promise library that does [promisification](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/blob/master/API.md#promisification), e.g. [Bluebird](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird).

Here is an example of how to promisify DynamoDB.

```js
var Promise = require("bluebird");

var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
var dynamoDbConfig = {
  accessKeyId: process.env.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
  secretAccessKey: process.env.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY,
  region: process.env.AWS_REGION
};
var dynamoDb = new AWS.DynamoDB(dynamoDbConfig);
Promise.promisifyAll(Object.getPrototypeOf(dynamoDb));
```

Not you can add `Async` to any method to get the promisified version.

Comment: worked great for me! i am using the new DynamoDB-doc lib. var docClient = new doc.DynamoDB();
Promise.promisifyAll(Object.getPrototypeOf(docClient));

Answer (score 15):

Way overdue, but there is a [aws-sdk-promise](https://www.npmjs.com/package/aws-sdk-promise) npm module that simplifies this.

This just adds a promise() function which can be used like this:

```
ddb.getItem(params).promise().then(function(req) {
    var x = req.data.Item.someField;
});
```

**EDIT**: It's been a few years since I wrote this answer, but since it seems to be getting up-votes lately, I thought I'd update it: `aws-sdk-promise` is deprecated, and newer (as in, the last couple of *years*) versions of aws-sdk includes built-in promise support. The promise implementation to use can be configured through `config.setPromisesDependency()`.

For example, to have `aws-sdk` return `Q` promises, the following configuration can be used:

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk')
const Q = require('q')

AWS.config.setPromisesDependency(Q.Promise)
```

The `promise()` function will then return `Q` promises directly (when using `aws-sdk-promise`, you had to wrap each returned promise manually, e.g. with `Q(...)` to get `Q` promises).

Comment: AWS Version 3 allows for modular use of AWS libraries, as opposed to required the whole aws-sdk. Is there a way to set the promise dependency of say, DynamoDBClient to a third party Promise when there is no global AWS config?

Answer (score 7):

With async/await I found the following approach to be pretty clean and fixed that same issue for me for DynamoDB.  This works with ElastiCache Redis as well.  Doesn't require anything that doesn't come with the default lambda image.

```
const {promisify} = require('util');
const AWS = require("aws-sdk");
const dynamoDB = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();
const dynamoDBGetAsync = promisify(dynamoDB.get).bind(dynamoDB);

exports.handler = async (event) => {
  let userId="123";
  let params =     {
      TableName: "mytable",
      Key:{
          "PK": "user-"+userId,
          "SK": "user-perms-"+userId
      }
  };

  console.log("Getting user permissions from DynamoDB for " + userId + " with parms=" + JSON.stringify(params));
  let result= await dynamoDBGetAsync(params);
  console.log("Got value: " + JSON.stringify(result));
}
```

Comment: This worked great for me with `AWS.CognitoIdentityServiceProvider`. Adding `bind` fixed the error `TypeError: this.makeRequest is not a function`.

Comment: Thanks!  You are correct, I've used this approach for every AWS SDK service successfully thus far, just copy, paste, refactor!  I like to wrap them into mini-libraries to maximize the readability of the main index.js code in Lambda as well.

Answer (score 5):

Folks,
  I've not been able to use the `Promise.promisifyAll(Object.getPrototypeOf(dynamoDb));`

However, the following worked for me:

```
this.DYNAMO = Promise.promisifyAll(new AWS.DynamoDB());
...
return this.DYNAMO.listTablesAsync().then(function (tables) {
    return tables;
});
```

or

```
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
var S3 = Promise.promisifyAll(new AWS.S3());

return S3.putObjectAsync(params);
```

Comment: You don't want to call `Promise.promisifyAll` as a constructor. Please omit the first `new`

Answer (score 1):

### [CascadeEnergy/aws-promised](https://github.com/CascadeEnergy/aws-promised)

We have an always in progress npm module `aws-promised` which does the bluebird promisify of each client of the aws-sdk. I'm not sure it's preferable to using the `aws-sdk-promise` module mentioned above, but here it is.

We need contributions, we've only taken the time to promisify the clients we actually use, but there are many more to do, so please do it!

Answer (score 0):

This solution works best for me:

```js
// Create a promise object
var putObjectPromise = s3.putObject({Bucket: 'bucket', Key: 'key'}).promise(); 

// If successful, do this:
putObjectPromise.then(function(data) {
 console.log('PutObject succeeded'); })

// If the promise failed, catch the error:
.catch(function(err) { 
console.log(err); });
```