# Asynchronous call inside a promise

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, promise, amazon-dynamodb

First of all I know this question has been asked many times, but I can't figure how to do this.
I am new to Node.js and dealing with the asynchronous aspect of it.

Here is my code

```
passport.use(new LocalStrategy({ usernameField: 'email', passwordField: 'password' }, function (email, pass, done) {   
    Users.query(email).exec(function (err, item) {
        const message = 'Login Invalid';
        if (err) return done(err);

        var promise = GetHash({ item, pass });        
        promise.then((data) => {                        
            return done(null, data)
        }).catch((err) => {
            console.log(err);
            return done(null, false, { message });
        });                             
    });    
}));

function GetHash(userPasswordRequest) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        if (userPasswordRequest.item && userPasswordRequest.item.Items[0]) {
            var userRecord = userPasswordRequest.item.Items[0].attrs;
            if (userRecord.old) {
                if (crypto.createHash('sha256').update(userPasswordRequest.pass, 'ucs-2').digest('base64') === userRecord.password) {
                    var newHash = bcrypt.hashSync(userPasswordRequest.pass, 10);
                    Users.update({ email: userRecord.email, password: newHash, old: null }, function (err, newItem) {
                        if (err) { console.log(err); } else {
                            console.log('first call');
                            resolve(newItem.attrs);
                        }
                    });                
                }
            }
            else {
                if (bcrypt.compareSync(userPasswordRequest.pass, userRecord.password)) {
                    console.log('first call');
                    resolve(userPasswordRequest.item.Items[0].attrs);                    
                }
            }
        }
        reject();
    })
}
```

The issue  is situated here :

```
 if (crypto.createHash('sha256').update(userPasswordRequest.pass, 'ucs-2').digest('base64') === userRecord.password) {
                    var newHash = bcrypt.hashSync(userPasswordRequest.pass, 10);
                    Users.update({ email: userRecord.email, password: newHash, old: null }, function (err, newItem) {
                        if (err) { console.log(err); } else {
                            console.log('first call');
                            resolve(newItem.attrs);
                        }
                    });                
                }
```

Because the `Users.update` is asynchronous, I'm rejecting the promise before resolving it.

I tried many things, a promise inside of a promise and many other stuff but I can't make this work properly.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: You wouldn't have everything inside one huge promise but split it out into a promise chain. So first get the user, then bcrypt it as two separate actions. If any part of the chain fails it aborts the chain and allows you to catch errors in one place throughout the chain.

Comment: Sounds like you simply are missing an `else` in front of the `reject()` call?

Comment: Are you using a particular promise library?

Comment: @Bergi I'm using the built in promise from Node.js 4.x

Comment: @Theo Btw, [dynamodb appears to already return promises](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26475486/how-do-i-promisify-the-aws-javascript-sdk) - so you don't need any `new Promise` at all

Comment: @Bergi I know but unfortunately I'm using another library call dynogels (there is a promise version of it but no documentation except for query and scan and I was not able to use .then on update)

Comment: @Theo File a feature request/bug report about that then :-)

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't use `reject` as a fall-through, but call is explicitly when an error condition occurs.

So like this:

```
if (userPasswordRequest.item && userPasswordRequest.item.Items[0]) {
  ...
} else {
  return reject(Error('invalid userPasswordRequest'));
}
```

And also:

```
if (bcrypt.compareSync(userPasswordRequest.pass, userRecord.password)) {
  console.log('first call');
  return resolve(userPasswordRequest.item.Items[0].attrs);                    
} else { 
  return reject(Error('invalid password'));
}
```

This isn't right either:

```
if (err) { console.log(err); }
```

Don't just log the error, reject the promise with it:

```
if (err) {
  console.log(err);
  return reject(err);
}
```

As you can see, it's also good form to return after resolving or rejecting.

Comment: Okay, I know that I can use else everywhere, but I was thinking that nicer solution exists

Comment: @Theo The nicer solution would be to use promises properly and promisify each asynchronous function separately :-)

Comment: @Bergi Yes! This is what I tried. Putting promise to other functions (especialy the call to the db) but I was not able to make it work

Comment: @Theo No, I meant your own functions should never call the `Promise` constructor. You should only use it to wrap `Users.query(…).exec`, `Users.update`, and the crypto functions if you used their asynchronous variants. Build a facade around the ugly callbacks, then use pure promises with `then` only.