# node.js module answer undefined

Tags: node.js

Can someone give me a hand? I tried to figure it out but i ran out of ideas.

-------------dynamo.js....

```
module.exports.readUser = function (user_id) {
    AWS.config = new AWS.Config();
    AWS.config.update({region:  "eu-west-1"});

    var docClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();
    var table = "user";
    var user_id = user_id;
    var params = {
        TableName: table,
        Key:{
            "user_id": user_id
        }
    };
    docClient.get(params, function(err, data) {
        if (err) {
            return err;
        } else {
            //console.log(data); <-- data is filled 
            return data;
        }
    });
```

---

```
var dynamo = require("./dynamo.js");
console.log(dynamo.readUser(4711998));
```

Comment: Can you explain the problem with more detail? Include console output if possible.

Comment: there isn't so much ubuntu@ip-172-31-21-157:~$ node test.js
ec2
undefined

Comment: data is filled with a json but console.log(dynamo.readUser(4711998)); gives only a undefined

Answer (score 0):

The data you log out inside the function is only the returned value for the anonymous function given to `docClient.get` as the second argument. The exported `readUser` function has no return statement and therefore it is undefined.

Because of the async nature of javascript you have to access the result via a callback like so:

```
module.exports.readUser = function (user_id, cb) {
    ...
    docClient.get(params, function(err, data) {
        if (err) {
            return err;
        } else {
            return cb(data);
        }
    });
}

var dynamo = require("./dynamo.js");
dynamo.readUser(4711998, function (user) {
    console.log(user);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`docClient.get` is an asynchronous function. You need promisify this function or use callback.

Use callback:

```
module.exports.readUser = function (user_id, cb) {
    AWS.config = new AWS.Config();
    AWS.config.update({ region: "eu-west-1" });

    var docClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();
    var table = "user";
    var user_id = user_id;
    var params = {
        TableName: table,
        Key: {
            "user_id": user_id
        }
    };
    docClient.get(params, cb);
}
```

---

```
var dynamo = require("./dynamo.js");

dynamo.readUser(4711998, function (err, user) {
    if(err)
        console.error(err);
    else
        console.log(user);
});
```

Use promise:

```
module.exports.readUser = function (user_id) {
    AWS.config = new AWS.Config();
    AWS.config.update({ region: "eu-west-1" });

    var docClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();
    var table = "user";
    var user_id = user_id;
    var params = {
        TableName: table,
        Key: {
            "user_id": user_id
        }
    };
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        docClient.get(params, function(err, data) {
            if (err) {
                reject(err);
            } else {
                resolve(data);
            }
        });
    });
}
```

---

```
var dynamo = require("./dynamo.js");

dynamo.readUser(4711998).then(function (user) {
    console.log(user);
}).catch(function(err) {
    console.error(err);
});
```

Read more:

[How do I promisify the AWS JavaScript SDK?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26475486/how-do-i-promisify-the-aws-javascript-sdk)

https://aws.amazon.com/ru/blogs/developer/support-for-promises-in-the-sdk/